# Classic ASP site is hanging occasionally

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, session-cookies

We have a classic ASP website on IIS 7.5.

Users are experiencing slow response randomly. When that happens, user cannot do anything for a few minutes which is very frustrating.

For example, I can open home page, then click few times through categories, and then website simply stops responding.

I didn't notice any rule when site will stop responding. Sometimes, it is working fine all time, sometimes it just stops.

When it is responding slowly, I can wait few minutes and then get the page. I tried to stop page load, and refresh the page, but that is not helpful. When this happen, I can't refresh the page, and I can't go to other page. Each page on site is not responding.

But, if I open other browser, let say I am in Chrome and open IE, site in new browser is fast again.

My only clue, if I delete ASP session cookie on client side, then loading of pages is fast again in same browser. So, it is obviously something related to ASP session cookie. Can IIS or ASP engine somehow block ASP session for some reason?

I noticed there is more chance for slow response if I click through site fast. It looks like after few fast clicks server maybe refuse that session for some reason?

Also, not sure if it is helpful and related to problem, I often see numerous different ASP session cookies. I suppose it should be only one session cookie per user in browser, but I see several different session cookies with different values.

Anyone ever saw something similar? Any idea how to resolve these occasional slow responses?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
I found when slow response happens, I cannot load even empty ASP page (I created page with one line of code, just with Response.Write "working"). 
Of course, if I open that page in another browser it works in no time. When problem happens, website is hanging only for that session. If I try same page in other browser or clear session cookie in same browser, page is loading fast.

Comment: The usual cause is a runaway DB query. Without knowing how your app works, this question is not very answerable.

Comment: I doubt it is database, because slow response could happen on each page. There is no rule. When problem happens, any page on site is not accessible. But, if I manually clear ASP session cookie, then site is fast again. Also, if I open another browser, and site will be fast too.

Comment: That's a toughie. You may want to post on serverfault.com instead. I don't think you'll gen an answer here.

Comment: How much info are you storing in your session cookie?

Comment: Look at IIS log for requests with long execution time and/or 500 in status code. Besides DB long response time, hanging may occur in external ActiveX component (ex. OWC). Also, check your code for infinite loops and application.lock/application.unlock statements.

Comment: @John, I am not storing anything in session cookie. ASP session cookie is generated automatically by ASP engine and it contains string of 24 characters.

Comment: @BorisP I presume John wondered what you store in your session variables.. pending on the number of users you could have issues if you store large disconnected recordsets for instance

Comment: @AardVark71, I see. Nothing much in Sessions, only few integers and short strings. It doesn't contain record sets or objects.

Comment: Post your cookie handling code and lets see if theres anything that jumps out at us in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer. The ASP website is using several custom COM components.

Some of these components are writing log files on disc. These logs are .txt files.

Log files grow over time, and one was over 4GB. Somehow, writing to big file caused server to respond slowly after loading of several pages. What is interesting, new browser window could open page fast when it is hanging in other browser.

So, I removed that part which writes to log files from ASP code, and website is now working without hanging.

Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

For such problems I just wrote a crude function (which I have in an include) and put in the problem page. The function writes out the timestamp, timer (to capture time in the millisecond range) and whatever other varibles I want to a text file.

I then just call the function before and after each suspicous section of code and after a few days check back to see what its found.

Remember to user timer() as part of this as the normal timestamp is usless for capturing time at a millisecond scale

Comment: wow, that's good idea. The page is hanging, but I am not sure where exactly. Since it is on random page, I suppose it is some include file.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, but looks like it is not related to any page. Then I click on links on website and after some time it is hanging. when that happens I cannot load even empty ASP page (I created one empty page to see if it page without code is working when site is hanging).

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. i do not have any databases, or any custom activex objects, I clean up every object (like scripting.filesystemobject) immediately after every action, but I do have sessions enabled in the application so that I can set the session codepage and so on. I do notice that the server generates a LOT of aspsessionid cookies; that is, by the time the page hangs, there might be 50 aspsessionid cookies. IIS generates these if sessions are enabled and there's nothing I can do about them. every 20-30 minutes, the page suddenly hangs in my session only. Bringing up another browser instance (e.g. another machine, or a private browsing mode) will respond again properly. Leaving the browser for 5 minutes will also cause it to start reponding properly. I know with loops I can check response.isclientconnected and do a response.end if they connection is dead to terminate the server process, but my client IS connected still, so that doesn't help.